# How to bulk install modules from local machine?

Tags: installation

Is there a way to install multiple modules at one from a local machine?

I've seen [quickupdate](https://www.drupal.org/project/quickupdate) but that is not from a local install, and relied on FTP which I cannot use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done quite simply.

1. Unzip and untar all the modules.
2. Copy them all into `apps\drupal\htdocs\sites\all\modules`.
3. Enable them on the modules page.

Answer (score 3):

You can just put them in one zip file, and upload using Drupal UI just as if they were one. Drupal will store them together, in  subdirectories just as you packed them. That's all, never been a problem for me.

Perfect example is, well, Examples project: http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/examples-7.x-1.x-dev.zip one zip, many functionally unrelated modules.

Comment: I had no idea drupal would 'understand' having several modules in a single zip. Amazing. Thanks.

Comment: @Pureferret That's how modules with "submodules" always worked. But there was no technological reason to force modules in one zip to be related. So they didn't. Simple as that :)

Comment: I have hit a snag in that drupal is expecting a .info file. Do I need to put all the modules together into one root folder with several .info files, or do I need to manually create one?

Comment: @Pureferret See the example zip I linked and just emulate what they did there.

Comment: I created a .info file but it didn't work, I had to untar all the files too. Now I have something that looks similar to the examples zip. I tried to install and it only installed the (alphabetically) first modules. Do I need a *.index.php files to link them all together?

Answer (score 0):

Use Drush.

```
drush dl x y z  
drush en x y z
```

Comment: Or just drush en x y z, drush will take care of the download.